# Combining 2 fields into 1 field

Tags: sql, sql-server

To explain what I'm trying to do I'll make a hypothetical situation. (Ignore bad db design lol)

3 tables:

```
Customers: CustomerID (pk), CustomerName
AM_Orders: OrderID (pk), OrderDateTime, TotalAmt, CustomerID (fk), OrderType
PM_Orders: OrderID (pk), OrderDateTime, TotalAmt, CustomerID (fk) OrderType
```

I want to generate a query that shows all customers LEFT JOINed to AM_Orders and PM_Orders, but I only want to have **ONE TotalAmt field**, not 2.

So, the result could be....

```
 ID  CName   TotalAmt OrderType
    1   Bob     $100     "AM"
    1   Bob     $10      "AM"
    3   Steve   $20      "PM"
    4   Tom     $20.45   "AM"
    5   Andy    $21      "PM"
    6   Jimmy
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can Left Join to a derived table that is a UNION of the two Orders tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slightly ambiguous, but it sounds like you want to `union all` the two results together:

```
select
    c.CustomerID ID,
    c.CustomerName Cname,
    o.TotalAmt,
    o.OrderType
from
    Customers c
        left join
    AM_Orders o
        on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
union all    
select
    c.CustomerID ID,
    c.CustomerName Cname,
    o.TotalAmt,
    o.OrderType
from
    Customers c
        left join
    PM_Orders o
        on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
order by
    ID;
```

or as Tab suggeted, union first then join. This might deal better with cases where there's an entry in one table but not the other:

```
;with all_orders as (
    select
        o.CustomerID,
        o.TotalAmt,
        o.OrderType
    from
        AM_Orders o
    union all
    select
        o.CustomerID,
        o.TotalAmt,
        o.OrderType
    from
        PM_Orders o
) select
    c.CustomerID ID,
    c.CustomerName Cname,
    a.TotalAmt,
    a.OrderType
from
    Customers c
        left join
    all_orders a
        on c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
order by
    ID;
```